# wordpress database select speed

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have select which is counting number of rows from 3 tables, I'm using wp function `$wpdb->get_var( $sql )`, there are about 10 000 rows in tables. Sometimes this select takes <1 second to load sometimes more than 15. If I run this sql in phpmyadmin it always returns number of rows in less than 1 second, where could be problem?

Comment: What type of hosting do you have?

Comment: I have vps which has 1 gb memory space, I'm really confused now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do.

First, do an analysis of your query. Putting `EXPLAIN` before the query will output data about the query and you may be able to find any problems with that.

Read more about `EXPLAIN` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html)

Also, WordPress may not have indexed the most commonly used columns.

Try indexing some of the columns which you most commonly use within your query and see if it helps.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD INDEX (post_author,post_status)
```

### Plugin

You could try a plugin such as [Debug Queries](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-queries/) which prints the queries onto the front-end and it helps debug where things are taking along time. This is recommended to run only in the dev area and not on a live website

Comment: data aren't in wp tables, they are in custom tables. exlain is returning this 
`id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 PRIMARY a ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 1852 Using where
3 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY c ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 2353 Using where
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY b ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 12198 Using where`

Comment: Reading that makes it pretty clear. No keys are indexed and the query which gets the 10,000 rows depends on 2 other queries which need to run first. You will need look into indexing some of the columns within your table's or look into streamlining your SQL query

Comment: but if I run sql query in phpmyadmin it takes less than second, couldn't be problem in something else? btw I'm using all columns in the same frequency, I have no idea which columns should I index

Comment: Could try a debug plugin. See amended Answer

Comment: Problems are probably caused with 2 almost similar queries: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a as a, table_b as b where a.category >= 0  b.id=a.id and (select AVG(rating) from table_rating as c where c.id=a.id)>=2.5 , there are more where clauses but it doesn't matter, is it possible to make this query more effective? (it is taking 10-15 seconds)

Comment: Have you looked into stored procedures? They're great for large data sets and if the query is going to be used a lot, its great for optimizing the speed of the queries within them. Read more here: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommending hooking up something like New Relic and trying to profile what's happening on the application side. If New Relic is not an option, you might be able to use xhprof (http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) and/or IfP (https://code.google.com/p/instrumentation-for-php/). Very few queries will perform the same in production in an application as they do in direct SQL queries. You may have contention, read locks, or any other number of things that cause a query from php to effectively stall on its way over to MySQL. In which case you might literally see the query running very fast, but the time it takes to actually begin executing that query from PHP would be very slow. You'll definitely need to profile what's happening on the way from WordPress to MySQL and back, based on what you're saying. The tools I mentioned should all be very useful for helping you accomplish that.